# How to UNNEST, GROUP and JOIN an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to **UNNEST** `cars.colors` array, then **GROUP** or group all colors in array and then join it. But it's so hur with it's nested **SELECT**s.

This is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/667d3/4) with example.

```sql
create table cars (
    cars_id integer,
    name    char(32),
    colors  int []
);

insert into cars (cars_id, name, colors) values
    (1, 'liftback',  array [1, 2, 3]),
    (2, 'hatchback', array [2, 4, 6]),
    (3, 'sedan',     array [3, 4, 6]),
    (4, 'phaeton',   array [4, 5, 6]);

create table tags (
    tags_id  integer,
    shade    char(16)
);

insert into tags (tags_id, shade) values
    (1, 'green'), (2, 'blue'),  (3, 'yellow'), (4, 'black'), (5, 'white'), (6, 'red');
```

But how to insert `array_agg` inside `unnest`?

```sql
SELECT
    cars.name,
    array_agg(tags.shade) AS shade_colors
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN tags ON cars.cars_id = tags.tags_id
GROUP BY cars.cars_id;
```

I whant to recieve smth like

[image]

[image]

Thats what I receive

[image]

Comment: What does color `array [1, 2, 3]` mean? How does 1, 2, 3 related to shades?

Comment: @zedfoxus i've added additional image, smth like that.

Comment: @zedfoxus by auto incremented keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (unnest first then array_agg again):

```
select a.name, array_agg(t.shade ) as shade_colors
from (
select c.cars_id, c.name, unnest(c.colors) as colorid
from cars c)a
left join tags t
on a.colorid = t.tags_id
group by a.name
```

Test Result:
[SQL<>Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/667d3/26)

Comment: Thanks a lot and, please, one more question: I've extended my ``car`` table with two similar integer arrays that alsaw join data from ``tags`` table http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83ce0/32 but I have some strange bug query - it returns arrays with length of 3, like the lenth of the first array, (I've added screenshot at the bottom of the question). As I understood this is because I've used three paralell UNNSET functions?

Comment: @khex The reason why its length is still three because you used 'Left Join'.

Comment: @khex You can ask a new question if you want the length equals to the array length.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried breaking into into pieces with a with statement?

```
with cars_qry as (
select cars_id, name, unnest(colors) as shade
from cars
)

select c.name, array_agg(t.shade) as shade_colors
from cars_qry as c
left join tags as t
   on c.cars_id = t.tags_id
group by c.name
```

or you could do it within the from statement:

```
from (select cars_id, name, unnest(colors) as shade from cars) as c
```

Comment: OP's existing query has one problem is to use car_id = tags_id. Tags_ids are for different colors(not for cars). So do not use his existing query.